# Google Maps API V3 Omnibox

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am attempting to use Google Maps API V3 as part of our system rebuild and want the maps to look and feel like standard Google maps. I have no issue with displaying the map but want to utilise the standard Google Maps Omnibox.

I can find all the individual controls but cannot find the complete Omnibox. Given the individual controls interact with each other I was hoping to simply use the standard Google Maps Omnibox to make the page look like standard a Google map.

Is this available or do I need to create one myself using the individual controls?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they provide the omnibox. But still, I think the closest thing you get is this: [the places search box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) in the places library.

it is basically nothing but an `<input type="text">`, which take advantages of the [places autocomplete api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete).

Comment: Thanks. That is what I have been discovering but was hoping I was wrong. We use maps as part of our system but this isn't the core functionality so hoped to keep as close to Standard Google maps so our users don't need to learn anything and ongoing design and development is reduced.